# Seeking Schema for vCard Data Elements

Tags: database-schema, vcf-vcard

I need a relational database schema to store vCard ver 3 data elements.

Rather than reading the RFC and designing one from scratch, I'm looking to see if someone who has already done this is willing to share their database design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: VCard 3.0 DB Specs]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/61qGU.png)

This is my DB schema for a VCard 3.0. This works quite well with CardMe library, each type is mapped to a database table and the many-to-many / one-to-many relationships are enforced through foreign keys.

```
CREATE DATABASE ERP;
CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_MAIL_ADDRESS
(
    MAIL_ADDRESS_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    POBOX VARCHAR(30),
    EXTENDED_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255),
    STREET VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LOCALITY VARCHAR(50),
    REGION VARCHAR(50),
    POSTAL_CODE VARCHAR(30),
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(MAIL_ADDRESS_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER
(
    PHONE_NUMBER_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    LOCAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,         -- Free form telephone number
    PRIMARY KEY(PHONE_NUMBER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_EMAIL
(
    EMAIL_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_AGENT
(
    AGENT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    URI VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(AGENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_CATEGORIES
(
    CATEGORY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CATEGORY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_NOTE
(
    NOTE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    NOTE TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(NOTE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_XTENDED
(
    XTENDED_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    XNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    XVALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(XTENDED_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_KEYS
(
    KEY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY_DATA TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(KEY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_DATA
(
    CONTACT_DATA_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    DATA_NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,             -- [LOGO,PHOTO,SOUND]
    URL VARCHAR(255),
    INLINE CHAR(1),
    DATA MEDIUMBLOB,
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_DATA_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_TYPES
(
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_ENCODING_TYPES
(
    ENCODING_TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ENCODING_TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FN VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    N VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NICKNAME VARCHAR(255),
    BDAY TIMESTAMP,
    MAILER VARCHAR(50),
    TZ INTEGER,                 -- Time zone offset in hours
    GEO_LAT DOUBLE,             -- Latitude
    GEO_LONG DOUBLE,            -- Longitude
    TITLE VARCHAR(50),
    ROLE VARCHAR(50),
    PROD_ID VARCHAR(255),
    REV VARCHAR(50),
    SORT_STRING VARCHAR(50),
    UID VARCHAR(255),
    URL VARCHAR(255),
    VERSION VARCHAR(10),
    CLASS VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_MAIL_ADDRESS
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    MAIL_ADDRESS_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(MAIL_ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_MAIL_ADDRESS(MAIL_ADDRESS_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,MAIL_ADDRESS_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_PHONE_NUMBER
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(PHONE_NUMBER_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER(PHONE_NUMBER_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,PHONE_NUMBER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_EMAIL
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_EMAIL(EMAIL_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,EMAIL_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_CATEGORIES
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_CATEGORIES(CATEGORY_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,CATEGORY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_NOTE
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    NOTE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(NOTE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_NOTE(NOTE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,NOTE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_DATA
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_DATA_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_DATA_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_DATA(CONTACT_DATA_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,CONTACT_DATA_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_AGENT
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    AGENT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(AGENT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_AGENT(AGENT_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,AGENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_KEYS
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(KEY_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_KEYS(KEY_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,KEY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_REL_XTENDED
(
    CONTACT_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    XTENDED_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT(CONTACT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(XTENDED_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_XTENDED(XTENDED_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_ID,XTENDED_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_MAIL_ADDRESS_REL_TYPES
(
    MAIL_ADDRESS_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(MAIL_ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_MAIL_ADDRESS(MAIL_ADDRESS_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_TYPES(TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(MAIL_ADDRESS_ID,TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER_REL_TYPES
(
    PHONE_NUMBER_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(PHONE_NUMBER_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER(PHONE_NUMBER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_TYPES(TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(PHONE_NUMBER_ID,TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_EMAIL_REL_TYPES
(
    EMAIL_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_EMAIL(EMAIL_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_TYPES(TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL_ID,TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_NOTE_REL_TYPES
(
    NOTE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(NOTE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_NOTE(NOTE_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_TYPES(TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(NOTE_ID,TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_KEY_REL_TYPES
(
    KEY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(KEY_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_KEYS(KEY_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_TYPES(TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(KEY_ID,TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_DATA_REL_TYPES
(
    CONTACT_DATA_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_DATA_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_DATA(CONTACT_DATA_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_TYPES(TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_DATA_ID,TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ERP.CONTACT_DATA_REL_ENCODING_TYPES
(
    CONTACT_DATA_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ENCODING_TYPE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(CONTACT_DATA_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_DATA(CONTACT_DATA_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ENCODING_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ERP.CONTACT_ENCODING_TYPES(ENCODING_TYPE_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(CONTACT_DATA_ID,ENCODING_TYPE_ID)
);
```

Comment: I'm curious what is the point of adding extra tables with mapping like CONTACT ID to TELEPHONE ID for example, it seems like redundancy for me.

Comment: I took an object oriented approach to model the database. Each contact can have 1 to many telephone numbers. So I couldn't put the telephone fields in the same table as Contact, maybe someone has 10 phone numbers. So many of the VCard types are related to the contact in a 1 to many relationship.