# vCard 4.0 database schema

Tags: xsd, database-schema, w3c, vcf-vcard, microformats

I need a database schema for the vCard 4.0 format.
Somebody already posted his schema for the 3.0 standard here [Seeking Schema for vCard Data Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459742/seeking-schema-for-vcard-data-elements). 
Should I just make some changes to his schema?

I could also take an .xsd schema and use it to generate a java object to help me create a database schema but I can't seem to find such an xsd.

Thanks